# WebLogic 10.3 Deployment Errors (WebApp 3.0 / Spring 4 MVC / Hibernate application)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, weblogic, weblogic-10.x

I am new to WebLogic and have developed my application on a different server.  I now have to deploy it to a WebLogic 10.3 server.  I uploaded the WAR file to the server and tried installing it.  I received the following errors:

```
Message icon - Error Unable to access the selected application.
Message icon - Error Exception in AppMerge flows' progression
Message icon - Error Exception in AppMerge flows' progression
Message icon - Error VALIDATION PROBLEMS WERE FOUND problem: cvc-enumeration-valid: string     value '3.0' is not a valid enumeration value for web-app-versionType in namespace http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee:<null>
```

I am concerned with the part where it states that the value 3.0 is not a valid enumeration value.  Does WebLogic 10.3 support web-app_3_0?  What about Spring 4?  or Hibernate 4?  I thought that we were using a later version...unfortunately we are stuck with 10.3.

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0" metadata-complete="true">
    <display-name>Contact Management Suite</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet> 
    <servlet-mapping>  
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems Weblogic 10.3 [doesn't support](http://wmarkito.wordpress.com/2011/01/19/java-standards-in-weblogic-10-3-4/) Servlet 3 spec. You would need to use, if possible, [Weblogic 12c](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24494/toc.htm#CJAEEHCI).

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have control over that.  If I did, I would be using the latest version.  I guess I'll need to change my code.  Hopefully it won't be too much!  This is my first project in this department - my last one was much more current in hardware and software, so I didn't realize it would be this low of a version.  Thanks for pointing me to that link.